# Mean/variance and Sample size Questions

Tags: statistics

Im currently studying for my end of year exams and am particularly struggling with 2 styles of questions. (1 being i cannot find any answers, the other being different wording). I would appreciate it very much if someone could help me and point me in the right direction with either of them. Thanks in advance.

1) A random variable X with a mean of 10 and a standard deviation of 10 is observed. You are interested in the mean and variance of a random variable Y which is a function Y=5X+5 (a) What is the mean of Y? (b) What is the variance of Y?

(Yes i know it seems easy and i might just be having a moment lol)

2) A random sample of 20 firms is taken with average firm profits of \$60 million and a variance of \$25 million. Which sample size should your survey have at a minimum?

(I have never encountered this style of question without confidence intervals/ levels)

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Hints for 1):


$\mathbb E(aX+b)=a\cdot \mathbb E(X)+b, \ 

Var(aX+b)=a^2Var(X)$

Comment: Thank you, would i be right in saying the mean is simply 5(10) + 5? And the variance is 5(10^2)?

Comment: The second problem is missing crucial information. Probably the desired width of a 95% confidence interval. Possibly something about a certain desired power when testing a hypothesis. Please look to see if additional information is lurking in the vicinity of the problem you copied.

Comment: @awetempz The expected value is right. The variance of $Y$ is $Var(5X+5)=25\cdot Var(X)=25\cdot 10$

Comment: @BruceET- This is exactly what i thought. With that information i can do the question no problems.

Comment: @callculus I would have thought that if in(1) $X$ has a standard deviation of $10$ then it has a variance of $100$

Comment: @Henry Good catch. Sure you are right.It So $Var(Y)=2500$. Argh...